# Introduce final variable by default in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I introduce new variable in IntelliJ IDEA using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, there is a "Declare final" option. It's unchecked by default. How can I make it checked by default?

Comment: In IntelliJ 12.0 it remembers your last choice. Which version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: Peter Lawrey, In 11.x it was configurable but I didn't find such option in 12.0. So it confused me. Thanks a lot. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be a special configuration, but it does remember the last choice you made.

(I just tested it to check ;)